# CSS Content - Line break

Tags: css

I want to do a line break with CSS. I´m using content.

```
    td:before {
                content: "Test\A Test2";
            }
```

It´s not working.
How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must add `white-space:pre;`

**Example**

```css
.linebreak:after{
    content:"A" '\A' "B";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="linebreak"></div>
```